# Can my Android source code be altered to allow users to call functions they arn't allowed to?

Tags: android, security, kotlin

Suppose I have the following code:

```
val debug = false 

fun createObj(name: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double){
    if (!debug) return
    functions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
    functions
        .getHttpsCallable("test")
        .call(hashMapOf(
            "name" to name,
            "latitude" to latitude,
            "longitude" to longitude,
        ))
}
```

If I push my production code with `val debug = false`, then in theory, users shouldn't have access to `createObj()`.

But is there any chance someone can change the value of debug?

Comment: Well, if they are decompile your code and change the value then they can access that function, but anyways anyone can do anything, for security purpose use a robust proguard. My suggestion would be using Firebase remote config to store these values.

Comment: Thanks Firebase Remote Config looks like a good security layer.